# Multi-module projects in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, project-structure, swift-package-manager

I'm developing an iOS application that is made of several distinct logical parts (i.e., "libraries").

What's the Swift way for creating such projects? How do I set it up in Xcode?

Comment: you can create a workspace and add them to it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways to do it:

- Using Xcode WorkSpace.
- Using Pod: https://cocoapods.org/
- Using incoming Swift Package Manager: https://swift.org/package-manager/

Happy coding